# Promotion But No Change in Salary?

Tags: tenure-track, promotion

Recently I received notification that my application for tenure and promotion to associate professor was approved. However, I have not yet received a letter indicating what this actually means as far as any potential changes in salary. Is it unusual not to find out what those changes would be when you are promoted from Assistant to Associate Professor? Or do you typically not find out until the beginning of the next semester?

Comment: Congratulations! Typically the promotion has an effective date (say, July 1st), which is also the effective date of the salary change. Why don’t you ask HR or the admin staff at your department for the details?

Comment: @DanRomik, that's probably better as an answer. Especially the last sentence.

Comment: As stated above, your admin can tell you more than we can. But for us to even try answering, we would need to know at least where in the world you are.

Comment: For my own experience from a few years back: I was notified of my promotion in late April, informed of a future corresponding increase in pay in mid-May, and given the raise at the beginning of the following Fall semester. Your mileage may vary greatly based on institution type, country, etc, but I can attest that it is not necessarily unusual for your letter about promotion to be devoid of pay details.

Comment: My university's Board of Regents usually approves promotions in May but waits until July or August to approve the university's budget for the coming academic year. So a newly promoted faculty member might get a letter today announcing the promotion but might not find out about next year's salary until August.

Comment: in my country, salary for university staff is regulated nationwide, depending on your position and the number of years you have already worked at the university and you could look up your salary in a table listing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on a specific department, I guess the best way to find out is to ask (the department head, or the business office of the department). For example, at our department, Assistant to Associate comes with "automatic" $5k salary raise, while Associate to Full has no automatic raise whatsoever...